# PerfMon and CLR Profiler counter comparison

Tags: performance, perfmon, performancecounter, clrprofiler

I am comparing Perfmon and CLR Profiler counters for my application.
I want to know that which perfmon counter relates to following CLR Profiler counter?

1. Allocated bytes
2. Relocated bytes
3. Final Heap bytes

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't miss the ".NET CLR Jit" category in the Add Counters dialog.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Can you please provide any link/hint regarding your comment?